# Having difficulty in understanding python user-defined functions

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

I am new to python. I searched on Google but didn't find an appropriate answer. What I am not understanding is, in the first program we can call `bar` function before its declared but in another program we can't call it before?

```
def foo():        
    bar()
def bar():
    print("hello")
foo()
```

**Output**:

```
hello
```

**Another code**:

```
bar()
def bar():
     print("hello")
```

> NameError: name 'bar' is not defined

Comment: The first program does not call ``bar`` before it is defined.

Comment: By the time flow-of-execution has reached the body of `foo`, bar has been defined. That's all that matters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are we able to call functions before they are defined in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62235073/how-are-we-able-to-call-functions-before-they-are-defined-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python reads your code from the top down. When you called `bar()`, it looked for where that was defined in the above code. It couldnt find it, so it threw an error. It is a good habit to define all of your functions first thing, so that python can always find them:

```
#functions
def foo():
   print("Hello foo")
def bar():
   print("Hello bar")
#end functions
foo()
bar()
```

Hopefully that was a clear explanation

Answer (score 2):

In the first code, you have *defined* something that calls `bar` before `bar` itself has been defined, but it doesn't actually get called until after you have started executing `foo`, which happens *after* `bar` has ben defined.

Answer (score 1):

You defined bar() after you called it. Instead, reverse the order:

```
def bar():
  print("hello")
bar()
```

Comment: I know that.but in first program why there is no error like in another program?

Comment: Because you define all the functions first, and then you call the relevant function AFTERWARDS, so that works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

In the first code snippet, though it appears that bar() is called before defining, it is actually not the case.
bar() is called inside foo() and bar() is defined before calling foo(). Therefore, bar() is defined before calling it.
In short, this is how it is actually being executed:
define foo() -- define bar() -- call foo() -- call bar().

However, in the second code snippet, bar() is called before defining it.

Hope that clarifies.